# MongoDB Zip Installation Failed in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb, openssl, libcurl, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install `MongoDB` from Zip Folder Downloaded From `MongoDB` site (https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/enterprise/releases/development)

I configured log path, data path correctly and trying to start `mongod` and getting following dependency error.

```
amran:~$ mongod
mongod: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by mongod)
```

`libcurl.so.4` exists in my machine

```
amran:~$ locate libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.5.0
```

How to fix this issue. Any Idea Please!

Comment: seems open ssl is missing, try to install it

Comment: sudo apt-get install openssl

openssl is already the newest version (1.1.0g-2ubuntu4).

Already Installed. Issue not solved yet.

Comment: found this hope it can help: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-version-curl-openssl-3-not-found/8090/4

Comment: uninstalled : sudo apt remove curl
installed: sudo apt install curl
But Yet not solved

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to do some custom things in order to run MongoDB 4.0  in Ubuntu 18.10.

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3
```

locate libcurl3 file likely in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

make an LD_LIBRARY folder in home.

```
 cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 /home/user/LD_LIBRARY
 mv /home/user/LD_LIBRARY/libcurl.so.4 /home/user/LD_LIBRARY/libcurl.so.3
```

make a link of libcurl3 by :

```
ln -s libcurl.so.3 libcurl.so.4
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/LD_LIBRARY/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

now start MongoDB it will run.

Also now you can install

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4 php-curl
```

And use all the application require php-curl and libcurl4

Comment: My mongodb 4 worked after `sudo apt-get install libcurl4 php-curl` Not before

Comment: Check out the issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-35885

Comment: It is closed :O is that mean is there a way to build this without getting this error? As I remember currently apt install give mongodb 3.6.3 I used the binary files

Comment: Worked for me. After `sudo apt-get install libcurl4 php-curl ` command, not before that in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic)

Comment: Running only the first step `sudo apt-get install libcurl3` worked for me.

Comment: Check out my answer below. Changing the installed curl version is a bad thing.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that this binary MongoDB distribution needs an older version of libcurl. In the other answers, the system is modified by globally installing an older version of libcurl, I **strongly** recommend against doing this as it will uninstall and/or break anything else that depends on the newer version.

Instead download a copy of the older library, extract the required binary, and preload it when running the mongod binary. This way you don't change anything else on the system, and as an added bonus you don't need root privileges to do it. Here's how:

First create a temporary directory, download the deb package and extract the file:

```
me@server:~$ mkdir tmp
me@server:~$ cd tmp
me@server:~/tmp$ apt download libcurl3
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libcurl3 amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 [214 kB]
Fetched 214 kB in 0s (9,969 kB/s)
me@server:~/tmp$ ar x libcurl3_7.58.0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
me@server:~/tmp$ tar xf data.tar.xz
```

Now copy the library to where your mongod binary is:

```
me@server:~/tmp$ cp usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.5.0 ~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-debian92-4.2.2-39-g38e05a1/bin/
```

You can make a wrapper for mongod so it preloads the required version of libcurl:

```
me@server:~/tmp$ cd ~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-debian92-4.2.2-39-g38e05a1/bin/
me@server:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-debian92-4.2.2-39-g38e05a1/bin$ mv mongod mongod.real
me@server:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-debian92-4.2.2-39-g38e05a1/bin$ cat > mongod
#!/bin/sh

DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
LD_PRELOAD=$DIR/libcurl.so.4.5.0 exec $DIR/mongod.bin $*
me@server:~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-debian92-4.2.2-39-g38e05a1/bin$ chmod 755 mongod
```

Now you can run mongod and it will work. Importantly you didn't make any changes to the installed packages on the system, and you don't need to use sudo for this to work.

Comment: typo mongod.bin -> mongod.real . This solution is the one that should have been marked as correct, thanks!

Comment: Which package would this be on Ubuntu 20.04?  `libcurl3` doesn't exist, and I have `libcurl3-gnutls` installed alongside `libcurl4`.

Comment: One can download it from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libcurl3/download - I got this solution from https://askubuntu.com/a/1154092/674834

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu version 18.04, it's better if you will install MongoDB manually.**

I had spent almost 3 hours adjusting dependencies with regular installation steps under the Mongo manual but nothing work.
Finally, I was given a try for manual installation and it surprisingly works perfectly fine for me.

**I need to go through the following steps to make it run on my Ubuntu 18.04:**

1. Fallow manual installation steps from the following mongo DB manual
   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-tarball/
2. Download .tgz with the following configurations
   [Download MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcLC2.png)
3. Please note, when you install MongoDB 3.6 or above, it comes up with Curl library of "libcurl4" version and which has some compatibility issues on ubuntu 18.04
4. Due to this, you will end up resulting following output when try to execute "mongod" command:

> mongod: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version
>   `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by mongod)

5. To fix this problem, you need to uninstall "libcurl4" dependent library by using the following command

   sudo apt-get remove libcurl4
6. Then need to install back lower curl lib version (i.e. "libcurl3"), as mongo expects it on ubuntu version "18.04"

   sudo apt-get install libcurl3
7. You may need to use "sudo" to fork the data and log directories with the installation if it fails with the manual steps

   sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
8. you can run "mongo" command now to see the mongo shell running.

Atleast it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

On the [downloads](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/enterprise/releases/development) page that you've shared, there is no mongodb version mentioned for Ubuntu 18.04.

You need to check with [mongodb](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user) if there is any release that is compatible with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You don't say what version of MongoDB you were trying to install. I ran into this when trying to install MongoDB 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.Perhaps downloading the source code for the Community Edition and checking if it would be an easy change to update to the libcurl.so.4.x. Otherwise, you can probably set up a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and install MongoDB 4.0 on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue (but on Debian 10) and I think my .so files were busted. Since I didn't have root access on the server I am using, I ended up copying libcurl.so.4 from my home computer (via SCP) to a new directory (like `LD_LIBRARY` in the accepted answer) and added that to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like in the accepted answer. I had to do this with two more files (libcrypto.so.1.0.0 and libssl.so.1.0.0) before running `mongod` on the server worked.

Hope this saves someone some time!

Answer (score 0):

I tried following different options :

Option1: with Ubuntu-16 mongo binaries (before option3 step2); if we are okay with libcurl3

```
1.  apt-get remove libcurl4
2.  apt-get install libcurl3
3.  able to start the daemon
```

Option2: didn’t work

```
1.  apt-get remove libcurl4
2.  apt-get install libcurl4
3.  /etc/init.d/mongo_db7020
/usr/bin/mongod: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /usr/bin/mongod)
```

Option3: copying mongodb 18 binaries worked

```
1.  apt-get remove libcurl4
2.  rsync -asvh mongoserver:/usr/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4/bin/* /usr/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1604-4.0.4/bin
3.  apt-get install libcurl4
4.  able to start the daemon
```

Option 1 & 3 worked fine for me.